# How to change the size of a texture that is in a group on Substance Painter

Tags: size, textures, substance

Is there a way to 'rasterize' like in Photoshop? to be able to apply a filter to the texture?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBox1.png)

I tried to apply a transform filter, but it only works with layers...

Comment: it's not possible.